# mercurial updated, mod_wsgi runs old version

Tags: centos, mod-wsgi, mercurial

I have a VPS with Centos 5.5, installed Python 2.6 following [Setup Python 2.5, mod_wsgi, and Django 1.0 on CentOS 5 (cPanel)](http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2008/11/10/setup-python-25-mod_wsgi-and-django-10-on-centos-5-cpanel/) tutorial and Mercurial 1.6 via easy-install.

Now I wanted to update to Mercurial 1.7.5, so I easy-installed it and it seemed to work.
At least when used from terminal.

I have been using `hgwebdir` to push/pull my reposisotires via HTTP. However, when I try to view a repository created with new `hg` (1.7.5), I get the 500 error page.
A look in Apache `error_log` reads something about dotencode support

```
 RepoError: requirement 'dotencode' not supported,
```

Google says it's a [problem when old `hg` tries to read a repository made with a new `hg`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RequiresFile).

How can I find out which `hg` is used by Apache/`mod_wsgi`? And how to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, it sounds like you WERE using mod_wsgi compiled against Python 2.5 (which has an old version of hg).  You are now trying to run mod_wsgi with Python 2.6 (which has hg 1.7.5).

Assuming you followed the instructions in the article you linked, you'll notice that you compiled mod_wsgi against the sources in Python 2.5. mod_wsgi doesn't launch a Python interpreter; instead, it calls into the Python sources directly.  So if you want mod_wsgi to work with Python 2.6, you'll have to recompile it with the Python 2.6 sources.

You can follow the same steps as the article, only using Python 2.6's sources instead of Python 2.5.  I've compiled mod_wsgi against Python 2.6 before, and the article looks like its spot on.

Hope this helps, and definitely leave comments if you encounter any issues.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like one of two things:

- you need to restart the webserver after installing the new version of Mercurial. When you use `mod_wsgi`, Apache will keep a copy of the script running in memory so that it can quickly serve new requests. So there might be a Mercurial 1.6 running in memory still. Restarting Apache should help.
- you've installed multiple versions of Mercurial on the machine. Try searching for `commands.py` and see if you find more than one version. Then remove the old version and re-install it as Redmumba suggests.